# Any tips or tricks to recognize lines better using HAAR cascades?

Tags: opencv, camera, image-recognition, haar-classifier

I'm currently developing an Android app for optical music recognition, using OpenCV. It must run in real time, not using photos. I created a HAAR cascade for the staff (five main lines), but it's incredibly slow (surely under 5 fps) and not so accurate. Isn't there a better way to do this? The problem is that I need it to recognize full width of those lines, but it instead recognizes many smaller lines inside.

[The real recognition is green, what I want is blue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fu11s.png)

C++ code:

```
String lines_cascade_name = "storage/emulated/0/data/haar_lines.xml";
CascadeClassifier lines_cascade;

std::vector<Rect> lines;
Mat frame_gray;

cvtColor( frame, frame_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY );
equalizeHist( frame_gray, frame_gray );

lines_cascade.detectMultiScale( frame_gray, lines, 1.1, 2, 0|CV_HAAR_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30) );

for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ ) {
    rectangle(frame, lines[i].tl(), lines[i].br(), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2, 8, 0);

    Mat faceROI = frame_gray( lines[i] ); Scalar( 255, 0, 0 ), 4, 8, 0 );
}
```

I need this first step settled, and then recognize notes and other symbols, and calculate where on the clef they are positioned, and play them when they intersect the middle line.

Wouldn't it be better to convert the preview to Canny, since it draws only the lines and edges?

If you had any ideas, I'd be very grateful.

EDIT:
So I'm trying to implement a Hough Lines Transform in C++, but I keep getting the "OpenCV Error: Unspecified error". The code is following:

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_ryu_musicreader_OpencvClass_musicDetection
(JNIEnv *, jclass, jlong addrRgba){
Mat& frame = *(Mat*)addrRgba;
find_lines(frame);
}

void find_lines(Mat& src){

Mat dst, cdst;
Canny(src, dst, 50, 200, 3);

cvtColor(dst, cdst, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);

vector<Vec4i> lines;
HoughLinesP(dst, lines, 1, CV_PI/180, 50, 50, 10 );

for( size_t i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++ )
{
    Vec4i l = lines[i];
    line( cdst, Point(l[0], l[1]), Point(l[2], l[3]), Scalar(0,0,255), 3, 0);
}

imshow("detected lines", cdst);
}
```

Included libraries are in my the header file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you use [Hough Line Transform](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)? Using that you will be returned `vector<4i>` which stores `x1, y1, x2 and y2` coordinates for each line.

Comment: Well, this is my first time with OpenCV and even C++, so I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing. But this looks really really helpful, I'll try it later and let you know. Thank you!

Comment: In that case I think you should also take a look at some mathematical formulas i. e. distance between vectors. From that you could find if 5 lines are close to each other or if there is space between them. Then you will be able to know which one is which. And to read on which one are the notes. If I were you I would look for notes and pauses using Haar casacades.

Comment: Well, I ran into a problem with this Hough Transform, when I try to use it in my .cpp file, my app crashes with unspecified error. I think it has to do something with the functions, although I have included everything that I should.